# Changing the count() cuts my results into multiple rows

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a hierarchy of objects, which can have relations to a different type of node at various levels. I'm trying to query one specific node with its relations to the other type of node, together with a list of its children with their relationships to the other type of node. And I want a count of all the distinct number of nodes of the other type.

Here's a query that works, but only counts the type2 nodes related to the top level object:

```
MATCH(root:Type1{id: {id}})-[:PARENT_OF*]->(child:Type1)-[:USES*]->(other2:Type2)
WITH root, child, collect(other2) as other2list, count(other2) as other2count
WITH root, collect(child {.*, otherCount: other2count, other: other2list}) as children
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:USES*]->(other1:Type2)
RETURN root {.*, arm: collect(other1), otherCount: count(other1), children}
```

This gives me exactly what I expect: a single result containing a hierarchy with root at the top, a list of its Type2 objects, and a list of its children, each with their list of Type2 objects.

However, I want the otherCount of the root to count all off the Type2 objects, whether they are connected to the root or to any of its children. Simply adding the counts won't do, because I don't want to count duplicates. (Don't worry, I'm familiar with `DISTINCT`; just leaving it out of this query for testing purposes.)

So I try passing along the collection of Type2 objects related to the children in order to count those:

```
MATCH(root:Type1{id: {id}})-[:PARENT_OF*]->(child:Type1)-[:USES*]->(other2:Type2)
WITH root, child, collect(other2) as other2list, count(other2) as other2count
WITH root, collect(child {.*, otherCount: other2count, other: other2list}) as children, other2list
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:USES*]->(other1:Type2)
RETURN root {.*, arm: collect(other1), otherCount: count(DISTINCT other1+other2list), children}
```

Now I suddenly get multiple rows. I suspect this is somehow caused by passing along other2list at the second `WITH` clause, but how else am I going to be able to count those objects?

Is there a way to do that in Cypher?

**EDIT:** The reason I'm not calculating the other2count earlier, is because I want to weed out duplicates with other1. (I just added the `DISTINCT` to make that clear.)

So here's an idea I had: to prevent early grouping (as pointed out by @cybersam below), I tried collecting the other2lists. Like this:

```
MATCH(root:Type1{id: {id}})-[:PARENT_OF*]->(child:Type1)-[:USES*]->(other2:Type2)
WITH root, child, collect(other2) as other2list, count(other2) as other2count
WITH root, collect(child {.*, otherCount: other2count, other: other2list}) as children, collect(other2list) as other2lists
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:USES*]->(other1:Type2)
RETURN root {.*, arm: collect(other1), otherCount: count(DISTINCT other1+other2lists), children}
```

This breaks the browser. At some point I did manage to get a weirdly distorted result from some variation of this that took over 9000 ms. No idea why this is such a problem, but I think packing them in a list of lists and later unpacking that list has to be part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `COLLECT` use all other non-aggregating terms in the same `WITH` or `RETURN` clause as grouping keys. So your last `WITH` clause is generating multiple rows.

This query may work better (it uses [apoc.coll.toSet](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_collection_functions) to get a collection of distinct `Type2` nodes):

```
MATCH(root:Type1{id: $id})-[:PARENT_OF*]->(child:Type1)-[:USES*]->(other2:Type2)
WITH root, child, COLLECT(other2) as o2list
WITH root, COLLECT(child {.*, otherCount: SIZE(o2list), other: o2list}) as children
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:USES*]->(other1:Type2)
WITH root, children, COLLECT(other1) AS arm
RETURN root {.*, arm: arm, children,
  otherCount: SIZE(apoc.coll.toSet(REDUCE(s = arm, c IN children | s + c.other)))}
```

Or, without using APOC:

```
MATCH(root:Type1{id: $id})-[:PARENT_OF*]->(child:Type1)-[:USES*]->(other2:Type2)
WITH root, child, COLLECT(other2) as o2list
WITH root, COLLECT(child {.*, otherCount: SIZE(o2list), other: o2list}) as children
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:USES*]->(other1:Type2)
WITH root, children, COLLECT(other1) AS arm
UNWIND REDUCE(s = arm, c IN children | s + c.other) AS o
RETURN root {.*, arm: arm, children, otherCount: COUNT(DISTINCT o)}
```

Comment: The problem with summing that early is that there's no way to remove duplicates at a later stage. I really need the original set, so I can later count distinct items. I need some way to pass it along without having it influence how the rest is grouped.

Comment: OK, I have revamped my query.

Comment: I need to check if I can install APOC on my instance. If not, would it be possible to get a similar result using COUNT and DISTINCT instead of SIZE and toSet?

Comment: Wow, that query is blazing fast. And the count seems to be correct. Thanks! I still need to understand how exactly that REDUCE works; I've never used it in Cypher, and it looks different from what I'm used to in other languages.